# How to break loop when int input is empty/blank?

Tags: python

I want the loop to break when user inputs empty/blank and cant figure it out.
Just gives me value error.

```
a = 0
x = 0
while True:
    num1 = int(input("Give number: "))
    if num1 == "":
        break
    x += num1
    a += 1
print("Numbers Given: ", a)
print("Sum of numbers: ",x)
```

Comment: How can `num1` be `""` when it's already been converted to an `int` ?

Comment: Either evaluate the input before converting it to `int`, or use `try`-`except`

Comment: That value error indicates you have to catch it to break the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = 0
x = 0
while True:
    num1 = input("Give number: ")
    if num1 == "":
        break
    x += int(num1)
    a += 1
print("Numbers Given: ", a)
print("Sum of numbers: ",x)
```

Comment: Thanks, i just started coding, dont know why i couldnt figure it out, seems so simple :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this try-except:

```
a = 0
x = 0
while True:
    try: 
        num1 = int(input("Give number: "))
    except ValueError as err:
        print("Empty `number`")
        break
    x += num1
    a += 1
print("Numbers Given: ", a)
print("Sum of numbers: ",x)
```

**Output:**

```
Give number: 2
Give number: 3
Give number: 
Empty `number`
Numbers Given:  2
Sum of numbers:  5
```